# Android permission denied when saving file from a non-UI thread

Tags: android, imageview, inputstream, permission-denied

I having trouble with the download of an image from a new thread and saving it into a file.

on some devices it works flawelsly

on others, such as the HTC INCERDIBLE, I am getting an exception

I managed to figure out it is in this line:

```
InputStream is=new URL(url).openStream();
```

this is the complete stack dump

```
import java.io.InputStream;

Bitmap bitmap=null;
InputStream is=new URL(url).openStream();
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
os.close();
```

```
D/dalvikvm( 1930): GC_EXPLICIT freed 26K, 47% free 3642K/6855K, external 0K/0K, paused 90ms
W/System.err( 2669): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/com.example.testing1/remote-image-cache/74110ca30e217cfdcc78a98f814de093c217bc07.hdr (Permission denied)
W/System.err( 2669):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
W/System.err( 2669):    at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:232)
W/System.err( 2669):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:94)
W/System.err( 2669):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:66)
W/System.err( 2669):    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:42)
W/System.err( 2669):    at org.appcelerator.titanium.util.TiResponseCache.put(TiResponseCache.java:359)
W/System.err( 2669):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.maybeCache(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:331)
W/System.err( 2669):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.retrieveResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1043)
W/System.err( 2669):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:512)
W/System.err( 2669):    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:645)
W/System.err( 2669):    at ti.testing.ImageLoader.getBitmap(ImageLoader.java:163)
W/System.err( 2669):    at ti.testing.ImageLoader.access$100(ImageLoader.java:29)
W/System.err( 2669):    at ti.testing.ImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(ImageLoader.java:256)
```

My manifest.xml file includes many permissions:

```
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

this is how I am getting the file path

```
   if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"LazyList");
    else
        cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
```

I don't understand it... Ideas ?

#### EDIT

I tried changing:

```
cacheDir=new File("/mnt/","emmc");
```

but now I get:

```
W/System.err( 404): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/emmc/cp_1216407347.jpeg 
(No such file or directory)
```

---

I tried changing cacheDir=new File("/mnt/","emmc"); but now I get W/System.err( 404): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/emmc/cp_1216407347.jpeg (No such file or directory)

Comment: just covering the basics (because I can't think of anything else really) are you sure that there is an SD card in all the phones ?

Comment: Adding to Jason's comment, some HTC phones have an internal storage mechanism that acts like a SD card but is accessed a different way. Are you by any chance hardcoding the /mnt/sdcard path?

Comment: the crash is before I am using the File, it is in openStream, so there is no file access attempted directly. I am adding a bit of code to my original question to show you how I am figuring out the path. Also, the HTC doesn't have a SDCARD, but other phone with one suffer from the same problem, while other work fine.

Comment: You're clearly getting a FileNotFoundException, try saving to /mnt/emmc instead of  /mnt/sdcard

Comment: Also check `Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY`

Comment: I tried changing cacheDir=new File("/mnt/","emmc"); but now I get W/System.err(  404): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/emmc/cp_1216407347.jpeg (No such file or directory)

Comment: have you try Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() instead of hardcode "mnt/"